# How to convert XML schemas (XSD) with 'choice' to RAML/YAML

Tags: xml, xsd, yaml, mulesoft, raml

I would like to ask how to convert XML schemas (XSD) to RAML/YAML schemas especially if my xml schemas has attributes like 'choice'.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xs:schema
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    
 <xs:element
 name="employee">
       <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
             <xs:element name="department">
                <xs:complexType>
                   <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="departmentname" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string" />
                   </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
             <xs:element name="experience">
                <xs:complexType>
                   <xs:choice>
                      <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="year" type="xs:positiveInteger" />
                      <xs:element name="grade" type="xs:decimal" />
                   </xs:choice>
                </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute name="employeeid" type="xs:string" use="required" />
       </xs:complexType>    
   </xs:element> 
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: You should not use quoted format for code, logs, or samples.

Comment: What exactly is a YAML schema?

Answer (score 0):

For RAML you need to be familiar with both specifications and try to translate the definitions from the XML Schema into a RAML specification. Specifically for the `choice` you could probably translate it to a [union type](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md#union-type). There are some tools that attempt to perform the conversion automatically, however since both standards are different there may be mismatches and you need to be prepared to complete the translation by hand.